# Context.startForegroundService() ANR without actually calling it

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, android-anr-dialog, foreground-service

After updating my app to target API 27 (previously 25) I'm encountering many ANR's from users, which I can't reproduce. They seem related to the Oreo background execution limits, with the ANR message

```
Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{73bc351 u0 com.xxx.xxxx/.player.PlayFileService}
```

However I do not call `Context.startForegroundService()` anywhere in my code. What are some reasons this ANR could be generated that are not a result of a direct call to this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, even though I didn't call `Context.startForegroundService()` directly, it was being called because my music app would go into the background and the service would be destroyed by the system. Then, when the user pressed a media button to resume playback after a couple minutes, the service would get restarted by the system, with that call since the app was in the background. I did call `startForeground()` eventually but it was after a bunch of configuration. I added a call to `startForeground()` at the beginning of `onCreate()` of my service with a blank notification and all my ANR's have disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation:

> Prior to Android 8.0, the usual way to create a foreground service was
>   to create a background service, then promote that service to the
>   foreground. **With Android 8.0, there is a complication; the system
>   doesn't allow a background app to create a background service**. For
>   this reason, Android 8.0 introduces the new method
>   **`startForegroundService()` to start a new service** in the foreground.
>
> After the system has created the service, the app has five seconds to
>   call the service's startForeground() method to show the new service's
>   user-visible notification. **If the app does not call startForeground()
>   within the time limit, the system stops the service and declares the
>   app to be ANR**

You can follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251528/android-o-old-start-foreground-service-still-working) which describes the approach to properly start the foreground service with Notification Channel.

Comment: I am doing it the old way. I only call startService() when app is in foreground, and call startForeground() when Activity goes to the background with a notification in a channel. Nowhere do I call the new startForegroundService() in my app.

Comment: @SteveM You cannot start an Service with `context.startService()` when your app is on background. You need to use `startForegroundService()`

Comment: I don't startService() with app in background. If I did that I would get IllegalStateException.

Comment: @SteveM just to be clear,  you are starting service when app is in foreground and when app goes to background you simply make it foreground ?

Comment: Yes, I call startforeground in onPause

Comment: @SteveM Have set NotificationId to non-zero value?