# Keep JobIntentService running with async task inside

Tags: android, android-service, text-to-speech, jobintentservice

I want to develop Text-To-Speech (TTS) feature in my app. It must be implemented inside `Service`, because user may leave "details" `Activity` and get back to "main" `Activity` or even leave my app, and it should still speak out loud text. Since Oreo introduced some background limitations for services and I must support 4.0+ I have to use `JobIntentService`

Problem is that TTS have async implementation and `JobIntentService` gets killed just after `onHandleWork` finishes its job, even when I use `startForeground` (in my code `showSpeakingNotification`)

Funny part is that when I but a breakpoint inside `onHandleWork` after 'speakOut' method or just uncomment `Thread.sleep` service is working and reading my text (and foreground notification is present).

Question is how to prevent "auto-killing" my service when it is actually running, but using asynchronous feature inside?

```
@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    if (ACTION_SPEAK.equals(intent.getAction()) && intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_TEXT_ARRAY)) {
        ArrayList<String> textArr = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_TEXT_ARRAY);
        showSpeakingNotification(textArr.get(0));
        if (ttsInitialized)
            speakOut(textArr);
        else if (ttsInitListener != null)
            ttsInitListener.setPendingText(textArr);
    } else if (ACTION_STOP_SPEAKING.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if (ttsInitialized && tts.isSpeaking())
            tts.stop();
    }
    try {
        //Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just uncomment Thread.sleep service is working and reading my text

When you add `Thread.sleep(10000);` it blocks the current thread as a result, it doesn't respond to your speech. When you comment it current thread is free to read your data

> Question is how to prevent "auto-killing" my service when it is
>   actually running, but using asynchronous feature inside?

Note possible. Your requirements can be fulfilled using Foreground Service. Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251528/android-o-old-start-foreground-service-still-working) for implementing the Foreground Service

Comment: with `Thread.sleep` its actually reading text out loud (for sleep duration), but it was only test, no the solution. Hopefully Foreground Service will work, I will check your link and get back with feedback or answer mark :) thanks!

Comment: @snachmsm sure.

Comment: @snachmsm great! enjoy coding