# Notification is not visible or not coming

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, foregroundnotification

I am trying to start the `startForegroundService()` in android `O` and above devices.

And the service got started. In the `onCreate()` method of the service, I have added the `startForeground()` with notification.

But the notification is not coming. I cant able to see it.

My code in the `onCreate()` method of the service:

```
  Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, "1")
          .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
          .setContentText("in app filling")
          .setAutoCancel(true);

  Notification notification = builder.build();
  startForeground(1, notification);
```

Comment: In Android O and Above, You need to have `NotificationId`... Have you tried it yet?

Comment: no, Can you refer some link. @Ümañgßürmån

Comment: Sorry, I meant `NotificationChannel` :)

Comment: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391826/6028722) should be able help you

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android O notifications should have the [`NotificationChannel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel) specified, otherwise they won't be displayed and the error would appear in the log.

You can read more on notification channels [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) and on foreground services in Api 26+ [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#4).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

**Step1:** Create a `NotificationChannel`

```
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channel_id , channel_name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
```

Here, channel_id and channel_name are `int` and `string` variables respectively.

**Step2:** Attach it to the `NotificationManager`:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
```

**Step3:** Create your Notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
                        .setContentTitle("Test Title")
                        .setContentText("Test Message")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

**Step4:** Attach the notification in the same `NotificationManager` object

```
notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
```

Finally, put up a check to notify if it's above Android O:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    ....
}
```

Referred and More about this can be found [Here](https://www.journaldev.com/19421/android-notification-channel-dots)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From Android version Oreo, You must have to add the channel to your notification like this:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

and create object for notification like this:

```
Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID")
```