# Android app show screen blink after kill app

Tags: android

I had an application program on Android 8.1.0 and my problem is:
After running this app about 15 minutes and go back to home screen and kill the app.
The screenshot of my app keep blink on my devices but can not interactive with this screenshot ( its show about 0.5s - 2s and disappear).

My app has some services running in the background but I had re-check the current running services on my devices nothing belong to my app is running after I kill it.

Please help me solve this case.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using `startForgroundServcie()` in your app. If used please provide the code of that.

Comment: Im using many services but none of them using startForeground(), are you have any other suggest to investigate this bug.

Comment: I think you need to add `startForeground()` with notification in `onCreate()` method in service class.

Comment: can you provide a sample code, and why we need do it, i just still dont understand 
 your solution yet, thanks @FaysalAhmed

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251528/android-o-old-start-foreground-service-still-working

Comment: And for more you can check this also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45047542/5167909